# Bundled css not displaying after deploy ... ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

When deploying my MVC application, the .NET 4.5 framework is bundling & minifying my CSS. However, the resultant file is empty, therefore the CSS rules are not applied. In Chrome, I get a `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain` warning. In IE9, I get a `CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch` warning.

This is what's in my BundleConfig

```
bundles.Add(
    new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
        "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-editable.css",
        "~/Content/bootstrap/FileUpload.css"));
```

Here is my Layout head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="@ViewBag.StyleUrl" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    <script src="~/scripts/libs/modernizr/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

The extra stylesheet is for a dynamically loaded stylesheet based on config in our Admin tool.

When I run this locally, or if I set debug="true", then I get my individual files & everything looks as it should. If I hardcode these in to my Layout page, they display fine. I've checked IIS & see the correct MIME type for CSS (which makes sense given that hardcoded values work). I've also checked to make sure the "Static Content" role service is installed, as I came across that in my googling as well.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show your css include in the html?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The bundle name is the same as the folder name on the filesystem,

Change your bundle to

```
bundles.Add(
new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapBundle").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-editable.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/FileUpload.css"));
```

i.e. so the name of the bundle is NOT the name of a folder or file

Comment: Awsome!! Saved my day.

Comment: I did that but then all css styles got messed. Using default template, for example, home dropdown menús stopped working, clicking doesnot drop anything down.

Comment: I had a similar problem but in my case I had a dot as part of the name of my bundle (the bundle was named error.handler). After removing the dot from the name of the bundle, it worked like a charm. I hope newer versions of ASP.NET MVC support this or at least warn us about it.

Comment: wow you save me a lot of time, i was luck today to bump in to the correct answer first

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My solution was the invalid name of bundle (it consisted of '_' or '.'). The name needs to be plain text:

```
bundles.Add(
new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap_Bundle").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-editable.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/FileUpload.css"));
```

had to be:

```
bundles.Add(
new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapBundle").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-editable.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap/FileUpload.css"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a product like dot defender, it can give you this error condition, too. When you bundle, if the cache buster parameter contains double dashes, then a product like dot defender sees that as a possible SQL injection attack and ends up interfering with the request/response.

One way to get around this (assuming you can't turn that software off) is to just add something to your original css file, like `.dotdefenderbuster {}`.

I need to check to see if the bundling algorithm has been updated to allow for influencing of the cache buster key.

For example:
http://www.foo.com/MyApp/Content/themes/MyApp/css?v=J9DBkvB7JWRo80eUukDOe3--6DAtA1